# How to create two equal columns with a fix space in between

Tags: html, css, html-table, multiple-columns

I have a table with `width:100%` and it should have 3 columns as follows:

`[50%-space/2][space][50%-space/2]`

Now, I have this already

```
<table style="width:100%"><tr>
   <td>left</td>
   <td style="width:20px"></td> //space
   <td>right</td>
</table>
```

This works fine, as long as there is always a "left" and "right" width the same width, but it stops working if one has a different width:

```
<table style="width:100%"><tr>
   <td></td>
   <td style="width:20px"></td> //space
   <td>right</td> // right takes all the space from the first td
</table>
```

And if I set "left" and "right" each to `50%`, the space in between is omitted:

```
<table style="width:100%"><tr>
   <td style="width:50%"></td>
   <td style="width:20px"></td> //space
   <td style="width:50%">right</td> // right takes all the space from the first td
</table>
```

Unfortunately, the space cannot be in `%` in this case (which would solve the problem easily). Also using CSS columns is not (yet) an option.

**Is there a solution for this?**

---

[<kbd>JSFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/r9D8Z/)

---

Comment: Any additional option which does not require a `<table>` is welcomed, as long as it does not use CSS columns.

Comment: Why don't you want to use "CSS columns" ? You're already using CSS, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Example**: http://jsfiddle.net/9yVx9/1/

---

use `table-layout: fixed` property

```
table {
    table-layout:fixed;
}
```

---

**Screenshot**
[image]